# Is the rendering of a transparent UIView free?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uiview

I understand that there's cost involved in rendering a semitransparent view over another view. What about a totally transparent view over another view. I.E. one whose background color is [UIColor clearColor].

Comment: nope, it's actually $20.  You can PayPal me if you want.

Comment: Make sure you don't implement `-drawRect:` and set your background color to `clearColor` and I think the render pass will not do any work.

Comment: @pixelbobby sounds reasonable enough. I'll write a note for my secretary to take care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily say "free." The `UIView` is being allocated memory. So, with respect to the memory usage, no, it's not "free." However, it will not require much work from the GPU, if and only if the alpha value (opacity) of the background color is exactly zero. If, like you said, you are using `clearColor`, the opacity is zero. If the opacity is not zero, the GPU has to blend colors, which will consume more graphics memory.